Advanced Search Email On Hold: checkbox or drop-down
It seems 1 out of 4 CiviCRM setups I've checked have the "Email On Hold" select.
Why? Is it something configurable? Drupal 7 - specific?

WordPress, CiviCRM 5.74.4  - check box
WordPress, CiviCRM 5.77.1 - check box
Drupal 10, CiviCRM 5.76.2 - check box
Drupal 7,  CiviCRM 5.77.0 - drop down



It depends on whether you have the setting "Enable multiple bulk email address for a contact" checked at CiviMail Component Settings.

I would never ever in my life figured this out, thanks!
